# Past participle of "spit"

Tags: verbs, past-participles, tenses, ablaut

Which is the past participle of *spit*: *spat* or *spit*? And how many examples can we come up with where a verb is changed in the simple past but unchanged(spelt like in the present) in the past participle?

Comment: It just depends on your particular dialect. Everyone agrees that past tense is the same as the present for words like *cut, hit, put*. In some dialects this also applies to *spit, shit* and probably others I can't call to mind offhand.

Comment: ...just thought of *quit*, where I think *quitted* is extremely rare. The opposite to most others.

Comment: Wikipedia already has a pretty complete [list of English irregular verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_irregular_verbs).

Answer (score 3):

My dictionary says:

> past and past part. spit or spat

which I take to mean that either is acceptable. However, if I were writing about some spit which had already been spat, I'd use "spat" as the past participle to describe the spit:

> spat spit

Using "spit" as the past participle in this case gives:

> spit spit

which doesn't sound right.

Comment: I suppose you'd have *shat shit* then? It's just your dialect - others would have *shit shit*, or even *shitted shit*.

Answer (score 2):

In standard English, you generally have:

- come, plus its compounds (including become)
- run, plus its compounds
- bid (bid / bade / bid), but generally not its compounds (e.g. "forbid" gives "forbidden")

Depending on your dialect, you could have variations on this, e.g.:

- many speakers nowadays conjugate "run" as run / ran / ran, so e.g. would say "it hasn't ran"
- some speakers conjugate compounds of "bid" in the same way as "bid", so e.g. "they've forbid him from coming"; on the other hand, many speakers also use "-bid" as the preterite, e.g. "they forbid it" meaning "they forbade it"; I'm not sure what percentage end up with "-bid / -bade / -bid"
- as mentioned above, one or two other verbs, in particular inherently slang verbs such as "shit", are candidates for variation so it seems that some speakers may end up with this A / B / A pattern for other verbs.

Answer (score 1):

There is:

> Come -> came -> come
>   Outrun -> outran -> outrun
>   Overcome -> Overcame -> Overcome
>   Rerun -> reran -> rerun
>   Run -> Ran -> Run

It seems to work only for the two verbs "come" and "run", and their subsequent compound verbs. Perhaps someone else could come up with a unique example.